# 301 redirect help - where am I going wrong?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to add a redirect for a specific page of our website.

I have managed to get it to redirect from the old page to the new page.

However the old page is still available from this URL:

http://the-arrow-group.co.uk/page.php?id=16 rather than actually redirecting to the new page..

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong for the page.php?id=16 portion??

Many, many thanks,

Tal

Comment: Can you show your redirect rule in question?

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that there is some configuration error with your redirect rule setup in your Apache configuration. The most likely culprit would be in a possible RegEx issue. Keep in mind that a match for "page.php" will only get that specific page. You would need to add the additional expression for the "?id=16" or ".*" (everything).

**tl;dr**:
RegEx redirect is likely wrong. Please post redirect rule.

Tuorials:

- [301 Apache Redirect Tutorial](http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/)
- [RegEx Tutorial](http://regexone.com/)